A Simple, Theft-Proof Connecting Wall
I recently made a fairly simple connecting wall, and I thought some people here might enjoy it. However, it has not escaped my attention that Puzzling has recently been the victim of a spate of letter thefts from connecting walls, and I did not want to fall victim to such a despicable crime.
So! I locked all my consonants in boxes. Then I locked all my vowels in boxes for good measure. Take that, letter thieves.

Oh, the colours? I ran out of blue boxes after finishing the consonants, so the vowels are all in red boxes.
Enjoy!
(Accessible version, with thanks to Benjamin Wang: CVCVCC - CVCCVC - CCVVCC - CCCCCC - CVCCCVCVCVVC - CVV - VCV - VCVVCCCCC - VVCVV - CVCCVCC - CCCVCCCC - CVVVV - CVCCVCVCC - VVCCC - CCCVCVCC - CVCVCCVC)
EDIT: DAGNABBIT, the thieves still got one letter. I've replaced it. (A letter has been added to the third row, third column.)

Love the premise and I think this is a great idea - I just hope it turns out to be more straightforward to solve than it seems on first viewing! :) Some of these patterns have a LOT of possibilities - I'm sure that finding certain ones will be key to unlocking these broader patterns...

@stiv I wonder if the lateral thinking tag is appropriate?

@PDT Hard to tell. There's a number of tags that might be appropriate: visual, letters, pattern, knowledge, etc.

rot13(Ippippipp piippiip ipp ipppip!)

I'm not sure I get it, does it mean letters in one box cannot be reused in the adjacent boxes?

I reckon the wall should be as follows (vowels in lower-case, Y considered as a consonant throughout):

 MeLoDY / CoNSTiTuTioN / eeRie / DeXTeRiTY
 WiSDoM / See (or Bee, or others) / HaRMoNY / aiTCH
 SPooKY / eYe (or eWe, or others) / STReNGTH / DYNaMiCS
 RHYTHM / uNeaRTHLY / Queue / SiNiSTeR

...where the categories are:

 Elements of music: Melody, Harmony, Rhythm, Dynamics

D&D attributes: Constitution, Dexterity, Wisdom, Strength

Words meaning 'creepy': Eerie, Spooky, Unearthly, Sinister

Homophones for letters of the alphabet: See (or Bee, or Dee, or any other consonant-vowel-vowel pattern), Aitch, Eye (or Ewe, or Are, or any other vowel-consonant-vowel pattern), Queue

While this looks a very imposing task at first, there are a few 'ins' for the puzzle:

 - The all-consonant 'RHYTHM' (allowing one to think about other properties in music theory);
 - The single-vowel 'STRENGTH' (allowing one to think about contexts in which that word might form one entry in a list);
 - The single-consonant 'QUEUE' (immediately suggesting letter homophones);
 - The rare patterns of consonants and vowels in 'UNEARTHLY' and 'EERIE', which together suggested a category to which they might both belong.


rlr pbhyq nyfb or n inevrgl bs bcgvbaf yvxr nlr, be ner, be rjr, be ...

Well done! Just beat me to it. I got sidetracked by VVCVV matching Eevee, and there being plenty of other matches for Pokemon.

@juicifer That's true, indeed. I also had reservations about this category because rot13(nvgpu) is really the word for itself, is it not? Still, it fitted very well.

@fljx I did the same! Until the typo in R3C3 was fixed I had SCRaGGY on the go too...

And (not sure if this was deliberate but works nicely), rot13(Lbh pna nyfb ercynpr qlanzvpf jvgu cuenfvat va gur zhfvpny frg)

Bravo! V'yy tenag gung nvgpu vf n ovg purrxl.

@BlueHairedMeerkat Ha! Well, I can see why you included it - its pattern has limited options. EIGHT was one of the others I was toying with before settling on this category...

Did you use some software to come up with candidate words with suitable vowel/ consonant patterns or was that all pen and paper (and lots of brain)?

@quarague I started off just using pen and paper for the unusual ones (disproportionate numbers of vowels or consonants) then thought around the possible categories with a thesaurus before using Qat with @ and # wildcards to help suggest more candidate lists to scan through (this helped me find Constitution and Unearthly, for example).

Partial answer
(assume no plural, assume nouns, assume common words, assume Y is a consonant)

 - CVCVCC
 - CVCCVC
 - CCVVCC
 - CCCCCC: RHYTHM


 - CVCCCVCVCVVC:  CONGREGATION / CONSTIPATION / CONSTITUTION / CONTRIBUTION / PERSPIRATION / SUBSTITUTION


 - CVV
 - VCV
 - VCVVCCCCC: UNEARTHLY


 - VVCVV: AUDIO / EERIE


 - CVCCVCC
 - CCCVCCC: SCRATCH / SCRUNCH / STRETCH


 - CVVVV: QUEUE


 - CVCCVCVCC
 - VVCCC: EARTH / EIGHT / YACHT


 - CCCVCVCC: PHRASING
 - CVCVCCVC

The others seem hopeless

I wouldn't say 'hopeless' :) My best attempt so far has 3 groups (including some of your words here) based off thinking around the 'most identifiable' patterns and how they might 'generate' possibilities in the other patterns...

Found and fixed my error, your fifth box is no longer correct.
